# Permuting an array with a given order without making a copy of the Array or a change to the order

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, permutation

I already found almost the same question asked here. But I need to do it a bit more complicated.

So here is the problem. You have an array with elements and another array with the specific order the elements of the first array should be in. Here is an example:

```
int[] a = {5, 35, 7, 2, 7};
int[] order = {3, 0, 2, 4, 1};
```

After the algorithm a should look like this:

```
a = {2, 5, 7, 7, 35};
```

The array named order must not be changed in any way and all copies of an array are forbidden. Only constant variables like a normal integer are allowed.

Note that this problem is not based on a specific language. It should be in a pseudocode-like language. Just understandable.

So does anyone here have an idea? I am sitting in front of this problem for 3 days now and hope to get some help because I think I am really stuck now.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the ranges of numbers shown you could:

- Add 100 times the corresponding order value to each item of a.
- Sort a.
- Replace every item of a by item modulo 100.

Some Python:

```
a = [5, 35, 7, 2, 7]
order = [3, 0, 2, 4, 1]

mult = max(a) + 1
a = [a_item + order_item * mult
     for a_item, order_item in zip(a, order)]
a.sort(reverse=True)
a = [a_item % mult for a_item in a]

print(a)    # [2, 5, 7, 7, 35]
```

I should emphasize that it works for the numbers shown; negatives and overflow considerations may limit more general applicability.

Answer (score 0):

The permutation defined by `order` consists of one or more cycles. It is straightforward to apply one cycle to array `a`, but the challenge is to somehow know which array elements belong to a cycle that you already processed in that way. If there is a way to *mark* visited elements, like with an extra bit, then that problem is solved. But using an extra bit is a cover-up for an array with additional data. So that must be ruled out.

When no possibilities exist to perform such marking, then there still is a way out: only perform the cycle operation on array `a` when you are at the left-most index of that cycle (or right most). The downside is that at every index you need to go through the cycle that index belongs to, to check whether you are indeed at its left-side extreme or not. This means that you'll cycle through the same cycle several times.

Here is how that looks in JavaScript:

```js
function isLeftOfCycle(order, i) {
    let j = order[i]; 
    while (j > i) {
        j = order[j];
    }
    return (j === i); // a boolean
}

function applyCycle(arr, order, i) {
    let temp = arr[i];
    let k = i;
    let j = order[i];
    while (j > i) {
        arr[k] = arr[j];
        k = j;
        j = order[j];
    }
    arr[k] = temp;
}

function sort(a, order) {
    for (let i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
        if (isLeftOfCycle(order, i)) {
            applyCycle(a, order, i);
        }
    }
}

// Example run:
let a = [5, 35, 7, 2, 7];
let order = [3, 0, 2, 4, 1];
sort(a, order);
console.log(a);
```

Obviously, this comes at a price: the time complexity is no longer *O(n)*, but *O(n²)*.